# Tensorflow Data API - prefetch

Tags: tensorflow, prefetch, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use new features of TF, namely Data API, and I am not sure how **prefetch** works. In the code below

```
def dataset_input_fn(...)
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, compression_type="ZLIB")
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x:parser(...))
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x,y: image_augmentation(...)
                      , num_parallel_calls=num_threads
                     )

    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)    
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

does it matter between each lines above I put `dataset=dataset.prefetch(batch_size)`? Or maybe it should be after every operation that would be using `output_buffer_size` if the dataset was coming from `tf.contrib.data`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In discussion on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7951)  I found a comment by mrry:

> Note that in TF 1.4 there will be a Dataset.prefetch() method that
>   makes it easier to add prefetching at any point in the pipeline, not
>   just after a map(). (You can try it by downloading the current nightly
>   build.)

and

> For example, Dataset.prefetch() will start a background thread to
>   populate a ordered buffer that acts like a tf.FIFOQueue, so that
>   downstream pipeline stages need not block. However, the prefetch()
>   implementation is much simpler, because it doesn't need to support as
>   many different concurrent operations as a tf.FIFOQueue.

so it means prefetch could be put by any command and it works on the previous command. So far I have noticed the biggest performance gains by putting it only at the very end.

There is one more discussion on [Meaning of buffer_size in Dataset.map , Dataset.prefetch and Dataset.shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444018/meaning-of-buffer-size-in-dataset-map-dataset-prefetch-and-dataset-shuffle) where mrry explains a bit more about the prefetch and buffer.

**UPDATE 2018/10/01**:

From version 1.7.0 Dataset API (in contrib) has an option to `prefetch_to_device`. Note that this transformation has to be the last in the pipeline and when TF 2.0 arrives `contrib` will be gone. To have prefetch work on multiple GPUs please use `MultiDeviceIterator` (example see [#13610](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13610#issuecomment-364331935)) [multi_device_iterator_ops.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/data/ops/multi_device_iterator_ops.py).

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/prefetch_to_device

Comment: Does it prefetch to gpu memory or to cpu memory? I cannot find the answer anywhere...