# TFRrecordDataset: Why and when use buffersize?

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I want to import a custom data sets with TFRecordDataset.
As I checked the docs I found myself wondering how I can benefit from setting a buffer_size?
Is it for very large data sets whre my memory can't handle the complete data?

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the answer to this question? 


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064693/tensorflow-data-api-prefetch)

Comment: [Found the answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444018/meaning-of-buffer-size-in-dataset-map-dataset-prefetch-and-dataset-shuffle) Thanks for the hint, D.negn.