# Can't use estimator + dataset and train for less than one epoch

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

TensorFlow 1.4 moves TF Dataset to core (`tf.data.Dataset`) and doc/tutorial suggest to use `tf.estimator` to train models.

However, as recommended at the end of [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets), the Dataset object and its iterator must be instantiated inside the `input_fn` function. This means the iterations through the dataset will start over for each call to `estimator.train(input_fn, steps)`. Thus, calling is with steps < number of samples in epoch, will lead to train the model on a subset of the dataset.

Thus my question. Is it possible to implement something like this with Estimator + Dataset:

```py
for i in range(num_epochs):
    # Train for some steps
    estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=valid_freq)

    validation_iterator.
    # Evaluate on the validation set (steps=None, we evaluate on the full validation set)
    estimator.evaluate(input_fn=valid_input_fn)
```

without starting training samples iterations from scratch at each call to `estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=valid_freq)`?

For example, unlike [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets), instantiate the Dataset and its iterator outside `input_fn`? I tried it but it does not work because then the input (from the dataset iterator) and the model (from the estimator `model_fn`) are not part of the same graph.

Thanks

Related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14283)

Comment: I have the same question?? Did you find a solution ??

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to make the training consistent across runs of `estimator.train()`.

However what you can do is make sure that you build the `train_input_fn` such that it will be random enough to obtain the same effect.

---

For instance suppose you have a dataset of values `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and you can only train on half the dataset at each call of `estimator.train`.
If you don't shuffle well enough, you will keep training on values `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`:

```py
train_size = 10
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(train_size)
x = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

sess = tf.Session()
for i in range(train_size // 2):
    print(sess.run(x))
```

---

However, if you call [`tf.data.Dataset.shuffle()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) with a `buffer_size` at least as large as the dataset, you will get random values.  Calling multiple times `estimator.train` with this will be equivalent to calling it one time with multiple epochs.

```py
train_size = 10
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(train_size)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=train_size)
x = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

sess = tf.Session()
for i in range(train_size // 2):
    print(sess.run(x))
```

I wrote another answer to explain the importance of `buffer_size` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48096625/5098368).

Answer (score 0):

You can return a `dataset` from your input_fn. Something like:

```
def input_fn():
  dataset = ...
  return dataset
```

To run evaluation without stopping training process, you can use [`tf.contrib.estimator.InMemoryEvaluatorHook`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/InMemoryEvaluatorHook)