# Access number of queued items in the TensorFlow Dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm changing my TensorFlow code from the old queue interface to the new Dataset API. With the old interface I could monitor the actual filled queue size by accessing a raw counter in the graph, e.g. as follows:

```
queue = tf.train.shuffle_batch(...,  name="training_batch_queue")
queue_size_op = "training_batch_queue/random_shuffle_queue_Size:0"
queue_size = session.run(queue_size_op)
```

However, with the new Dataset API I can't seem to find any variables in the graph related to the queues / datasets, so my old code doesn't work anymore. Is there any way to obtain the number of items in the queue using the new Dataset API (e.g. in the `tf.Dataset.prefetch` or `tf.Dataset.shuffle` queue)?

It is important for me to monitor the number of items in the queue, as that tells me a lot about the behaviour of the pre-processing in the queues, including whether the pre-processing or the remainder (e.g. a neural network) is the speed bottleneck.

Comment: please, have a look at [46444018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444018/meaning-of-buffer-size-in-dataset-map-dataset-prefetch-and-dataset-shuffle) to get a better idea of the underlying behavior of the different kinds of shuffle arguments

Comment: @maxF. Yes, I understand. The example in my post is perhaps not the best, since it is interesting to monitor `tf.train.shuffle_batch` in the old setting, but it makes no sense to monitor `tf.Dataset.shuffle` in the new setting. What does make sense to monitor is the size of `tf.Dataset.prefetch`, to get an idea of whether the pre-processing or the actual network is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around it is possible to keep a counter to indicate how many items are in the queue. Here's how to define the counter:

```
 queue_size = tf.get_variable("queue_size", initializer=0,
                              trainable=False, use_resource=True)
```

Then, when pre-processing data (e.g. in the `dataset.map` function), we can increment that counter:

```
 def pre_processing():
    data_size = ... # compute this (could be just '1')
    queue_size_op = tf.assign_add(queue_size, data_size)  # adding items
    with tf.control_dependencies([queue_size_op]):
        # do the actual pre-processing here
```

We can then decrement the counter every-time we run our model with a batch of data:

```
 def model():
    queue_size_op = tf.assign_add(queue_size, -batch_size)  # removing items
    with tf.control_dependencies([queue_size_op]):
        # define the actual model here
```

Now, all we need to do is run the `queue_size` tensor in our training loop to find out what the current queue size is, i.e. the number of items in the queue at this moment:

```
 current_queue_size = session.run(queue_size)
```

It's a bit less elegant compared to the old way (before the Dataset API), but it does the trick.