# How to get number of samples in a tf.dataset for steps_per_epoch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

i am curious how I can set the steps_per_epoch in tf.keras fit for training on a tf.dataset?. Since I need the number of examples to calculate it I wonder how I get this?

As it is of type tf.data you could assume assume that this is more easier. If I set steps_per_epoch to None I get "unknown".

Why using tf.data makes life so complicated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous answer is good, yet I would like to point out two matters:

1. The code below works, no need to use the experimental package anymore.

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(42)
#Still prints 42
print(dataset.cardinality().numpy())
```

2. If you use the `filter` predicate, the cardinality may return value -2, hence unknown; if you do use filter predicates on your dataset, ensure that you have calculated in another manner the length of your dataset( for example length of pandas dataframe before applying `.from_tensor_slices()` on it.

Another important point is how to set the parameters `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` : `steps_per_epoch == length_of_training_dataset // batch_size, validation_steps == length_of_validation_dataset // batch_size`

A full example is available here : [How to use repeat() function when building data in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509425/how-to-use-repeat-function-when-building-data-in-keras/60509810#60509810)

Comment: Thank you! But I am really confused. I use repeat(2) after the dataset (actually I dont really know what this does). How do I set the steps_per_epoch now to get all data in each epoch? Do I now set the steps count as twice of the previus value because of repeat(2)?!

Comment: Steps_per_epoch == length_of_training_dataset // batch_size, validation_steps == length_of_validation_dataset // batch_size

Comment: I get -2. my dataset is of type FlatMapDataset .

Comment: Told you it could happen. Then you need to somehow calculate prior the length. In some way I understand why it returns -2, because when you flatten, you don't know how many elements you get. Ensure that you calculate the length prior to avoid any problem.

Comment: So as for my understanding. Working with plain tf.dataset without repeat just goes through the whole data once at maimum per epoch? So i need repeat() and set steps_per_epoch as all number of batches?

Comment: Regardless of tf.dataset , when using .fit() steps_per_epoch = dataset_length // batch_size, and yes, this is the total number of batches given a specific batch_size.

Comment: And you need to specify .repeat() on the actual training_set and validation_set that you send to the .fit() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try `tf.data.experimental.cardinality`:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(42)
print(tf.data.experimental.cardinality(dataset).numpy())

42
```