# what does cardinality mean in relation to an image dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, math, tensorflow-datasets

After successfully creating a tensorflow image `Dataset` with:

`dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(...)`

which returns

*Found 21397 files belonging to 5 classes.
Using 17118 files for training.*

There is the cardinality method:

`dataset.cardinality()`

which returns a tensor containing the single value

*tf.Tensor(535, shape=(), dtype=int64)*

I've read the [docs here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/cardinality) but I don't understand what 535 represents or why its different to the number of files?

I ask, because I would like to understand how cardinality plays into this equation:

`steps_per_epoch = dataset.cardinality().numpy() // batch_size`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cardinality, in your case, is simply the rounded number of batches:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(180, 180),
  batch_size=batch_size)

print(train_ds.cardinality())
```

```
Found 3670 files belonging to 5 classes.
Using 2936 files for training.
tf.Tensor(92, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

The equation is: `2936/32 = cardinality`, so it depends on your batch size.

Comment: This answers my question, thank you very much! still not sure I fully understand the "why" behind it

Comment: It just returns the batched size of your dataset. Nothing special.

Comment: but then why is our cardinality divided by our batch size our steps per epoch? shouldn't that be number of files?

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059811/how-to-get-number-of-samples-in-a-tf-dataset-for-steps-per-epoch