# How to speed up batch preparation when using Estimators API combined with tf.data.Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I'd like to speed up my training routine that uses the Estimator API with input_fn wrote using `tf.data.Dataset`.

My implementation takes 2 second to prepare a batch of data and then runs training on GPU for 1 sec, and then start over preparing a batch. Which is really inefficient.

I'm looking for a way to prepare the batches asynchronously and upload them to GPU to speed up the training. Or alternatively for a way to cache datasets between invocations of `input_fn` (the `dataset.cache()` doesn't seems to be a good choice as the dataset has to be recreated on each input_fn invocation).

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
def input_fn(filenames, labels, epochs):
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
  dataset = dataset.map(_read_wav, num_parallel_calls=num_map_threads)
  if shuffle:
     dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=len(labels))
  dataset = dataset.map(_post_process,  num_parallel_calls=num_map_threads)
  dataset = dataset.map(lambda wav, label: ({'wav': wav}, label))
  dataset = dataset.batch(128)
  dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs) # to iterate over the training set forever
  iterator = dataset.dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  features, labels = iterator.get_next()
  return features, labels

train_input_fn = lambda : input_fn(train_files, train_labels, None)
eval_input_fn = lambda : input_fn(eval_files, eval_labels, 1)

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=45000)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=eval_input_fn) 
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

I've noticed that the Estimator API is under active development and in the master branch of tensorflow the input_fn can return datasets already, so maybe I'm asking too early and this feature isn't ready yet. But if so, please provide a ticket where this implementation can be tracked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `tf.data.Dataset.cache()` is indeed not a good choice since it will cache the whole dataset into memory, which takes time and might overflow your memory.

The way to go is to use [`tf.data.Dataset.prefetch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch) at the end of your pipeline, which will always make sure that the data pipeline holds `buffer_size` elements. It is usually enough to have `buffer_size = 1` at the end:

```py
dataset = ...
dataset = dataset.batch(128)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)  # prefetch one batch
```

As explained by @mrry in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47025850/5098368), you can also try to increase the number of prefetched batches a bit.

> Typically it is most useful to add a small prefetch buffer (with perhaps just a single element) at the very end of the pipeline, but more complex pipelines can benefit from additional prefetching, especially when the time to produce a single element can vary.

---

If you still have a slow input pipeline compared to your GPU computations, you need to increase the number of threads working in parallel using the `num_parallel_calls` argument of [`tf.data.Dataset.map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map).

Comment: @Olivier: according to documentation, prefetch(1) means prefetching 1 example, rather than one batch, right?

Comment: This will prefetch one example of the current dataset. Since we batched the dataset just above, the current dataset contains batches of `128` images so it will prefetch one batch.

Comment: I think important note is that you can cache even if data don't fit into the memory. Tensorflow allows caching into the filestorage if you specify the filename as argument: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache

Answer (score 1):

A few points to add to Olivier's answer, mostly from [this post](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance):

- `repeat` before `shuffle` is slightly faster, at the downside of blurred epoch boundaries. This may be significant in rare cases, but I doubt it.
- `shuffle` before `map`ping - this reduces the memory foot print of your shuffle buffer size, since it only needs to buffer the filenames rather than the file contents.
- it makes more sense to me to apply the third map transform to the output of `get_next()` rather than the dataset - not sure if that affects speed much. You could also consider putting both other map calls in the same one to reduce scheduling issues.
- experiment with `repeat` before `batch`ing. Probably won't make a difference, but might be minor. If you `repeat` before `shuffle` as mentioned above you'll have to.
- as mentioned by Olivier, use `prefetch`.

Code with modifications:

```
def input_fn(filenames, labels, epochs):
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
  dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs)
  if shuffle:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=len(labels))

  def combined_map_fn(*args):
    return _post_process(_read_wav(*args))

  dataset = dataset.map(combined_map_fn, num_parallel_calls=num_map_threads)
  dataset = dataset.batch(128)
  dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)

  iterator = dataset.dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  wavs, labels = iterator.get_next()
  features = {'wav': wavs}
  return features, labels
```