# How to use tf.data.Dataset with kedro?

Tags: tensorflow, pickle, tensorflow-datasets, kedro, tf.data.dataset

I am using [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) to prepare a streaming dataset which is used to train a tf.kears model. With [kedro](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), is there a way to create a node and return the created `tf.data.Dataset` to use it in the next training node?

The [`MemoryDataset`](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.io.MemoryDataSet.html?highlight=memorydataset#) will probably not work because `tf.data.Dataset` cannot be pickled (`deepcopy` isn't possible), see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862492/how-to-save-tf-data-dataset-object). According to [issue #91](https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/issues/91) the deep copy in `MemoryDataset` is done to avoid modifying the data by some other node. Can someone please elaborate a bit more on why/how this concurrent modification could happen?

From the [docs](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.io.MemoryDataSet.html#kedro.io.MemoryDataSet.__init__), there seems to be a `copy_mode = "assign"`. Would it be possible to use this option in case the data is not picklable?

Another solution (also mentioned in issue 91) is to use just a function to generate the streaming `tf.data.Dataset` inside the training node, without having the preceding dataset generation node. However, I am not sure what the drawbacks of this approach will be (if any). Would be greate if someone could give some examples.

Also, I would like to avoid storing the complete output of the streaming dataset, for example using [`tfrecords`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord) or [`tf.data.experimental.save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/save) as these options would use a lot of disk storage.

Is there a way to pass just the created `tf.data.Dataset` object to use it for the training node?

Answer (score 0):

Providing workaround here for the benefit of community, though it is presented in [kedro.community](https://discourse.kedro.community/t/how-to-use-tf-data-dataset-with-kedro/124/2) by @DataEngineerOne.

According to @DataEngineerOne.

> With kedro, is there a way to create a node and return the created
> tf.data.Dataset to use it in the next training node?

Yes, absolutely!

> Can someone please elaborate a bit more on why/how this concurrent
> modification could happen?
>
> From the docs, there seems to be a copy_mode = "assign" . Would it be
> possible to use this option in case the data is not picklable?

I have yet to try this option, but it should theoretically work. All you would need to do is create a new dataset entry in the `catalog.yml` file that includes the `copy_mode` option.

Ex:

```
# catalog.yml
tf_data:
  type: MemoryDataSet
  copy_mode: assign

# pipeline.py
node(
  tf_generator,
  inputs=...,
  outputs="tf_data",
)
```

I can not vouch for this solution, but give it a go and let me know if it works for you.

> Another solution (also mentioned in issue 91) is to use just a
> function to generate the streaming tf.data.Dataset inside the training
> node, without having the preceding dataset generation node. However, I
> am not sure what the drawbacks of this approach will be (if any).
> Would be greate if someone could give some examples.

This is also a great alternative solution, and I think (guess) that the `MemoryDataSet` will automatically use `assign` in this case, rather than its normal `deepcopy`, so you should be alright.

```
# node.py

def generate_tf_data(...):
  tensor_slices = [1, 2, 3]
  def _tf_data():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor_slices)
    return dataset
  return _tf_data

def use_tf_data(tf_data_func):
  dataset = tf_data_func()

# pipeline.py
Pipeline([
node(
  generate_tf_data,
  inputs=...,
  outputs='tf_data_func',
),
node(
  use_tf_data,
  inputs='tf_data_func',
  outputs=...
),
])
```

The only drawback here is the additional complexity. For more details you can refer [here](https://discourse.kedro.community/t/how-to-use-tf-data-dataset-with-kedro/124/2).