# What does BUFFER_SIZE do in Tensorflow Dataset shuffling?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, generative-adversarial-network

So I've been playing around with this code: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan and have almost developed a good idea about its functioning. However, I can't quite discover what is the **BUFFER_SIZE** variable's use. I suspect that it may be used to create a subset of the database of size **BUFFER_SIZE** and then the batches are taken from this subset, but I don't see the point on it and neither can find someone explaining it.

So, if someone could explain me what **BUFFER_SIZE** does, I would be thankful ❤

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of buffer\_size in Dataset.map , Dataset.prefetch and Dataset.shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444018/meaning-of-buffer-size-in-dataset-map-dataset-prefetch-and-dataset-shuffle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used as the `buffer_size` argument in `tf.data.Dataset.shuffle`. Have you read the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle)?

> This dataset fills a buffer with `buffer_size` elements, then randomly samples elements from this buffer, replacing the selected elements with new elements. For perfect shuffling, a buffer size greater than or equal to the full size of the dataset is required.

> For instance, if your dataset contains 10,000 elements but `buffer_size` is set to 1,000, then shuffle will initially select a random element from only the first 1,000 elements in the buffer. Once an element is selected, its space in the buffer is replaced by the next (i.e. 1,001-st) element, maintaining the 1,000 element buffer.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of TensorFlow, the `buffer_size` define a random first element between the size of buffer_size. After choose this random one, the next numbers will follow the size of `buffer_size`

samples = 1000 
buffer_size = 100

choose a random between (0, 100) 
random = 37 
the sample will be (37 to 137)