# What is tensor Rank?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I came through tensor slices and tensor rank. I read a lot of material related to this but could not satisfy myself.

Can anyone explain thoroughly with the help of examples, specifically in the view of TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.rank` is like `array.ndim` in NumPy. It's the number of dimensions. E.g., a picture has rank 3:

```
640, 640, 3
```

A batched picture dataset has rank 4:

```
10000, 640, 640, 3
```

Tabular data has rank 2:

```
150, 4
```

It's that simple. Let me know if I should add anything.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks alot

Comment: can you explain `dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(self.train_batch_size)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64372390/im-trying-to-understand-what-buffer-size-in-dcgan-does/64372547#64372547